# Checking if a text file has another line Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a script to parse text files into a spreadsheet for myself, and in doing so I need to read through them. The issue is finding out when to stop. Java has a method attached when reading called `hasNext()` or `hasNextLine()` I was wondering if there was something like that in Python? For some reason I can't find this anywhere.

Ex:

```
open(f) as file:
    file.readline()
    nextLine = true
    while nextLine:
        file.readline()
        Do stuff
        if not file.hasNextLine():
            nextLine = false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical cadence that I use for reading text files is this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:

    lines = myfile.readlines()

for line in lines:

    if 'this' in line: #Your criteria here to skip lines
        continue

    #Do something here
```

Using `with` will only keep the file open until you have executed all of the code within it's block, then the file will be closed. I also think it's valuable to highlight the `readlines()` method here, which reads all lines in the file and stores them in a list. In terms of handling newline (`\n`) characters, I would point you to @Joe Iddon's answer.

Comment: You make the `with open` as almost pointless by storing all of the lines in a variable do you not? Thats how our answers differ :)

Comment: It incurs the same amount of overhead, so no. I believe this is more readable, especially when you want to `enumerate(lines)` and reference a specific index inside of the `lines` list.

Comment: Ended up using that if statement and checking if there's a new line in it, due to being able to read lines that don't exist in python, they just come up as empty strings

Comment: Try `print(repr(line))`

Comment: Shall we time them and see? :D

Comment: @Swift is right, there's no need to stay inside the `with` block after `readlines()`. Indenting the code implies that it's still interacting with the file in some way, i.e., at first glance a lot of people would think your code is iterating over the file, which it isn't. Unindenting would also fit the mantra that 'Flat is better than nested.'

Comment: Oh I totally misunderstood the point @Swift was making, my fault. You are correct, I will update.

Comment: would this empty the file upon completion?

Answer (score 6):

Just use a for loop to iterate over the file object:

```
for line in file:
    #do stuff..
```

Note that this includes the new line char (`\n`) at the end of each `line` string. This can be removed through either:

```
for line in file:
    line = line[:-1]
    #do stuff...
```

or:

```
for line in (l[:-1] for l in file):
    #do stuff...
```

---

You can only check if the file has another line by reading it (although you can check if you are at the end of the file with `file.tell` without any reading).

This can be done through calling `file.readline` and checking if the string is not empty or [timgeb's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954457/checking-if-a-text-file-has-another-line-python/51954486?noredirect=1#51954674) of calling `next` and catching the `StopIteration` exception.

So to answer your question exactly, you can check whether a file has another line through:

```
next_line = file.readline():
if next_line:
    #has next line, do whatever...
```

or, without modifying the current file pointer:

```
def has_another_line(file):
    cur_pos = file.tell()
    does_it = bool(file.readline())
    file.seek(cur_pos)
    return does_it
```

which resets the file pointer resetting the file object back to its original state.

e.g.

```
$ printf "hello\nthere\nwhat\nis\nup\n" > f.txt
$ python -q
>>> f = open('f.txt')
>>> def has_another_line(file):
...     cur_pos = file.tell()
...     does_it = bool(file.readline())
...     file.seek(cur_pos)
...     return does_it
... 
>>> has_another_line(f)
True
>>> f.readline()
'hello\n'
```

Comment: Or you could just use `line.strip()`

Comment: @rahlf23 that would not just remove the `'\n'` in some cases.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this due to different lines going to different places, or being skipped due to their content, each loop through needs to handle around 40 lines, it's just sectioned off to a point where I don't know how many sections per file, just exactly what each section contains

Comment: True, you're right @timgeb, I'm just assuming the user wouldn't be concerned removing leading and trailing whitespace characters

Comment: @yourknightmares why do you change the requirements of your question to something nobody could have expected after getting a correct answer? That usually makes the answerer pull their hair out and not help you in the future. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: @timgeb I didn't change my answer, what I asked was simple. Is there a way to check if a file has another line. This answer works in half the cases, tops. He should know that

Comment: @yourknightmares right, strictly speaking all you were asking is how to check whether there's a line left. Your context is so special however that there was no reason to assume that "well, when the for loop ends" is not the applicable answer. Anyway, I tried to answer your question in  more general terms.

Comment: the file.realine() would break if there are intentional blank lines in the file, wouldn't it? just tested it and it just returns a blank string. so was the string intentional or just the return_on_failure ? sometimes python is really messy. the second approach is gud tho

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(filepath, 'rt+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        #code to process each line
```

Opening it this way also closes it when it's finished which is much better on the overall memory usage, which might not matter depending on the file size.

The first lines is comparable to:

`f = open(....)`

`f.readlines()` gives you a list of all lines in the file.

The loop will start at the first line and end at then last line and shouldn't throw any errors regarding EOF for example.

[Edit]

notice the 'rt+' in the open method. As far as I'm aware this opens the file in read text mode. I.e. no decode required.

Comment: I think we were answering at the same time

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't have an end-of-file (EOF) indicator, but you could get the same effect this way:

```
with open(f) as file:
    file.seek(0, 2)      # go to end of file
    eof = file.tell()    # get end-of-file position
    file.seek(0, 0)      # go back to start of file
    file.readline()
    nextLine = True      # maybe nextLine = (file.tell() != eof)
    while nextLine:
        file.readline()
        # Do stuff
        if file.tell() == eof:
            nextLine = False
```

But as others have pointed out, you may do better by treating the file as an iterable, like this:

```
with open(f) as file:
    next_line = next(file)
    # next loop will terminate when next_line is '', 
    # i.e., after failing to read another line at end of file
    while next_line:
        # Do stuff
        next_line = next(file)
```

Comment: consider the case where the file pointer is at a byte halfway along the last line: this method would say "yes" to "do I have another line?" whereas you really don't. It is unavoidable that you must read up to the next line break (`\n`) to determine if you have another line. The only other thing you can do is reset your file pointer so you are at least in the same state as before you checked :/

Comment: @JoeIddon, I assume the code is using `readline` or `next()` (as shown), in which case it will never stop mid-line. But even if the code were reading byte by byte, and currently positioned mid-line, the next `readline` would return the rest of the current line. More relevant would be the case where the remaining text doesn't make a full line, i.e., doesn't have a newline at the end. Then my test would return `True` and `readline` or `next()` will still read the remaining text, even with no terminating newline. Would Java's `hasNextLine()` return False in this case?

Comment: I don't know about this special case in Java. Your code doesn't quite work as it stands (`false` and `!=` are incorrect) but I like the logic.

Comment: @JoeIddon You're right about that. I had the "hasNextLine" idea in mind, which is equivalent to `file.tell() != eof`, but this code actually negates that. I've fixed it now.

Comment: happens all the time +1

Answer (score 1):

Files are iterators over lines. If all you want to do is check whether a file has a line left, you can issue `line = next(file)` and catch the `StopIeration` raised in case there isn't another line. Alternatively you can use `line = next(file, default)` with a non-string `default` value (e.g. `None`) and then check against that.

Note that in most cases, you know that you are done when the `for` loop over the file ends, as the other answers have explained. So make sure you actually need that kind of fine grained control with `next`.